# git: code removed with automatic merge

Tags: git, merge

A while ago we branched away from main version A to a new branch B. Few days after that, some new arguments have been added to a method in a file in main A.
Besides that, those lines of code haven't been touched on both sides (meaning, the B branch has still the original set of fewer arguments).

Now, roughly 9 months later, we wanted to merge B back into A. The merge removed the added arguments from A again.

What is the reason behind that, and how can we find other similar issues or the places/commits/picks/merges that are responsible for such a behavior?

Used tools: we use SmartGit

Comment: What command did you use *exactly* to merge the branches?

Comment: Did you check that lines were not touched with `git annotate`? Maybe someone did a reformat which changed just the line ends.

Comment: Git's merge is not always 100% perfect.  You can always just add back the missing lines in your IDE.

Comment: The command was "> git.exe merge --no-commit --no-ff"
And yes, I looked at "blame" and the whole history

Answer (score 0):

Further investigation showed that there was at some stage a commit where the faulty file was not in the commit (not discarded, just not selected). Implicitly those changes were taken as a "throw away" in the future.

This commit didn't appear in the faulty file's history obviously, because it was not changed with the faulty commit.

What can be done to solve:
- re-merge the two versions of the faulty commit again into a new local version
- cherry-pick that commit into the current version
These are our findings. If anyone has a better solution, feel free to post here.